# Getting strange integer value from $_COOKIE

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i am storing some data with cookies, i can see the content in the front-end with javascript and the dev tools but when i try to retrieve the cookies with PHP i get some integers values.
[image]

this is my PHP code

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['generationData']) && isset($_COOKIE['generationData2'])){
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

this is the console print

```
array(12) {
  ["generationData"]=>
  string(10) "1591470747"
  ["generationData2"]=>
  string(10) "1591470761"
  ["_swa_u"]=>
  string(36) "4f965d38-b5af-444a-b6e7-9548e73bb5b5"
  ["_fbp"]=>
  string(28) "fb.1.1590707745689.769529022"
  ["_fbc"]=>
  string(80) "fb.1.1590710226078.IwAR0YcJqSufZ8TQl0rn-5wBntBBi3cKSZCVftk7FQKq4WZIiO6Ls2IIEAE-s"
  ["wordpress_test_cookie"]=>
  string(15) "WP Cookie check"
  ["tk_ai"]=>
  string(28) "woo:lyRAD5qg30woty8wdWO65TwP"
  ["_lscache_vary"]=>
  string(32) "5604b5b26f2ceca50009f0afc43b6e45"
  ["wp-settings-1"]=>
  string(71) "libraryContent=browse&hidetb=1&editor=tinymce&imgsize=&unfold=1&mfold=o"
  ["mailchimp_landing_site"]=>
  string(65) "https://chilewatt.cl/wp-admin/post.php?post=1045&action=elementor"
  ["wp-settings-time-1"]=>
  string(10) "1591407865"
```

the actual values for `['generationData']`  cookie is

```
%7B%22fullAddress%22%3A%22Rep%5Cu00fablica+de+Austria+1655%2C+Angol%2C+Araucan%5Cu00eda%2C+Chile%22%2C%22kwGenerated%22%3A5.076153846153847%7D
```

The code for creating one of the cookies:

```
if(isset($_POST['averageBill'])){
        $averageBill = intval($_POST['averageBill']);
        $kwPrice = intval($_POST['kwPrice']);
        $jsonString = json_encode(array('kwPrice' => $kwPrice, 'averageBill' => $averageBill));
        if(isset($_COOKIE["generationData2"])){
                setcookie("generationData2",time() -3600);
                setcookie("generationData2",$jsonString,time() + (86400 * 30),"/","",true,false);
            }
            else{
                setcookie("generationData2",$jsonString,time() + (86400 * 30),"/","",true,false);
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide in text what your image contains.

Comment: And the code that creates the cookies

Comment: Sure the outputs are from the same site? I don't see the `AWSALB`, `AWSALBCORS` or `spin` cookies from the image in your cookie dump

Comment: Yes, the generationData cookies are from local domain, and the AWSALB,AWSALBCORS are external. from analytics.sitewit.com, spin from facebook.